# Which preference can I add in python selenium ChromeDriver options to allow unsafe-downloads?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

now I must disable the following Chrome flag:

```
chrome://flags/#treat-unsafe-downloads-as-active-content
```

which prefs I can use in `webdriver.ChromeOptions` like `"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2` to instead of modifying the flag?

Answer (score 0):

```
 safebrowsing.enabled:false
```

Set this flag to false ,

Reference :
https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/24751883?hl=en

The below link shows supported preferences is in chrome options :

https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/common/pref_names.cc?view=markup

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  
  "safebrowsing.enabled": False
})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: It doesn't work ,with error:
`This file should be served over HTTPS. This download has been blocked. See https://blog.chromium.org/2020/02/protecting-users-from-insecure.html for more details.`

Comment: Could you try options.add_arguments("--allow-running-insecure-content")

Comment: Thank you very much, but it still doesn't work as the same error